# How to calculate the relative frequency per groups

Tags: r

I want to calculate the relative frequency per groups.

This is my dataset:

```
CATEGOTY   VALUE  COUNT
AAA        1      230
AAA        0      150
BBB        1      155
BBB        0      320
```

The expected result is this one, where `PROC` is obtained by dividing `COUNT` by the sum of `VALUE==0` and `VALUE==1` per group:

```
CATEGOTY   VALUE  COUNT   PROC
AAA        1      230     0.60
AAA        0      150     0.40
BBB        1      155     0.33
BBB        0      320     0.67
```

In fact I received the first grouped dataset using this code:

```
set = df %>%
  group_by(CATEGORY,VALUE) %>%
  summarise(COUNT = n())
```

So, I want to know how to adjust this code in order to get one more column `PROC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with base R:

```
df$PROC <- round(ave(df$COUNT, df$CATEGOTY, FUN=function(x)x/sum(x)),3)
df
#  CATEGOTY VALUE COUNT  PROC
#1      AAA     1   230 0.605
#2      AAA     0   150 0.395
#3      BBB     1   155 0.326
#4      BBB     0   320 0.674
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(CATEGOTY) %>% mutate(PROC = round(COUNT/sum(COUNT),1))

#  CATEGOTY VALUE COUNT  PROC
#     <chr> <int> <int> <dbl>
#1      AAA     1   230   0.6
#2      AAA     0   150   0.4
#3      BBB     1   155   0.3
#4      BBB     0   320   0.7
```